# How to adapt C++ lambdas to a sink interface such as back_inserter et al

Tags: c++, lambda, adapter

I would like to know if its possible without having to define an extra class, if a lambda can be adapted to act as a sink.

For example we currently can do the following:

```
std::vector<int> ilst;

std::copy(ilst.begin(),ilst.end(),std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout,"\n"));
```

What if something like the following could be possible? obviously the following wont
compile atm:

```
std::copy(ilst.begin(),ilst.end(),
          [](const int& i)
          {
             std::cout << i << "\n"; 
          });
```

I've been able to get around this problem, by defining a function object that implements dereference and function operators  and takes a lambda as a predicate.

However I was wondering if there is some kind of C++ voodoo that will allow for the above without the need for an extra intermediary class to be provided?

Comment: Remember that there is an adaptor already: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/iterator/doc/function_output_iterator.html

Comment: @avakar: Already mentioned I'm looking for solutions that get around having such an adapter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot do this without an adapter object.

`std::copy` takes an output iterator which conforms to the standard library output iterator requirements. A lambda function is an object that has an `operator()` that takes certain arguments and returns a value. These are two different kinds of things.

If you have an interface that takes Y, but you have a X, the *only* way to reconcile this is to introduce a Z that converts X into Y.

And since X and Y are objects, Z must therefore be an object that provides the Y interface, but internally converts it into an X. Z is commonly called an adapter object.

There is no alternative "C++ voodoo" that's going to change this. There is no "other solution". You *must* use some kind of adapter. Whether it's a temporary of a class type or a function that returns an instance of a class, this can only be resolved with an adapter object.

---

Applied to this particular situation - X is a lambda, Y is an output iterator, and Z is a [function_output_iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iterator/doc/function_output_iterator.html):

```
#include <boost/function_output_iterator.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm/copy.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> ilst;
    boost::copy(
        ilst,
        boost::make_function_output_iterator(
            [](int i) { std::cout << i << "\n"; }));
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but as stated in the question, I am already aware of such adapters and was looking more for other kinds of solutions - providing an answer to something that has been specifically stated as not being required or wanted is obviously not in the SO way, Rather it's something someone trolling for points would happily do.

Comment: @JaredKrumsie: You asked, "However I was wondering if there is some kind of C++ voodoo that will allow for the above without the need for an extra intermediary class to be provided?" And I answered: "The 'C++ voodoo' you use is called an adapter object, which translates one interface to another. This is not only the correct solution, but it is the _only_ solution." You can choose not to believe that answer of course. But that will not make it any less true ;)

Comment: I agree that it is "a" solution as I stated the current solution I was using was that, however i was interested in other solutions. You presented an answer that essentially repeated what I said, and yet somehow you magically got 3 votes, seems like puppet voters are alive and well and following Mr Nicol. ;D

Comment: @JaredKrumsie: I'm not sure what the problem is. You asked for "other solutions". _There are no other solutions_, which is what I thought that I clearly stated in my answer. But, since you insist, I'll make it the first line, so that it's clear.

Answer (score 0):

Would this do what you expect?

```
std::for_each(ilst.begin(),ilst.end(),
          [](const int& i)
          {
             std::cout << i << "\n"; 
          });
```

I suspect that this example is a stand-in for something more complicated, where for_each is unsuitable. Is this so?